# Hosing a website within a Wordpress directory/folder

Tags: customization, directory

I have a blog that is hosted on the Wordpress Business plan.

I'd like to create a website within the blog. The website is in fact only one page, but is structured completely different from the blog. How can I do this?

To be clear, here is my [blog](http://thembaisdead.com) and here is the page I want to create:

[image]

In other words, my blog is at thembaisdead.com, while I envision the above page (screenshot) at thembaisdead.com/accelerators.

All help apreciatiated!

Comment: Is this wordpress.com? As apposed to self hosted?

Comment: Yes. Hosted with Wordpress. I’m not hosting it